# No exact matches in call to instance method 'remove' in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

Try to delete tableViewCell in swift XIB. but there is error cannot remove models

**viewModel :**

```
private var combinedItems: [combinedInboxModel] = []

func get(){} // Add combinedItems data
```

**View Controller**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {                    
        viewModel.combinedItems.remove(at: indexPath.row) // No exact matches in call to instance method 'remove' in swift
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)                    
    }
}
```

Why there is error remove here?

Comment: combinedItems Is declared `private` in the view model so you can’t access it from your view controller.

Comment: silly me , thanks @JoakimDanielson

Comment: can i also ask out of topic, is there any tableview. delete section (not delete rows) ?@JoakimDanielson

Comment: There is according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614922-deletesections)